# Can Colorbox browse admin/content/media from Media rather than file uploads?

Tags: files, javascript, media

Is it possible to configure Colorbox for Drupal D7 to use content already stored by the Media module (in admin/content/media) rather than use a file upload? The alternative is either:

1. Upload duplicate images per node (e.g. article, page...)
2. Link to the original image which requires the author to search nodes to find the image and copy/paste the URL while risking a broken image if the original node is deleted (i.e. the image is deleted with the node).

Thanks

Comment: The Media module has a media browser that can allow users to easily search for and insert media without worrying about paths at all. It is point and click and media is re-used, not duplicated. In the manage fields UI of your content type, change the Image widget to 'Media browser'. You can also add the [File Lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_lock) module which allows you to lock files against accidental deletion.